# Way to activate hover when in the vicinity of the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a bunch of elements on a page that when hovered show a menu. Because hovering requires to be on the element and if you are right at the border it gets very tricky to activate them iIwas wondering if there is a way to activate the hover menu when the mouse is close to the element, let's say at a tolerance rate of 10 pixels from any border (N,S,E,W).

Tracking the mouse on the page is really not an option, too much processing needed on the client side and the page is already loaded with lots of javascript code.

Comment: Consider increasing the padding of those elements - that will give you a larger hover area.

Comment: Just create an invisible container div that is slightly longer and wider and wraps around each menu element. Then have the hover logic applied to that div so it will set off before it hits the actual menu item.

Comment: all these solutions won't apply as i am also using some other js logic that cannot be messed with. I am also making the containers resizable and draggable...can't increase padding, the resizable handlers are exactly at the margin of the container...looking for a different solution

Answer (score 2):

I think wrapping the menu item content with a div / span element and then applying the hover styles to that would work best. And then as Sime said, increase the padding on the menu item.

For example the html would be:

```
<ul class="menu">
   <li><span>content here</span></li>
</ul>
```

Then the CSS would be something like:

```
li {
     padding:10px;
}

li:hover span {
      /* Hover style of menu item here */
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a solution that would fit all your criteria. You can either: track the xy location of the mouse and elements that you want to activate a hover on. Or wrap the hover element with another element (this can be done through JS as well). I am unaware of any other way of achieving the final outcome.